# Difference between double colon and arrow in perl

Tags: perl

If it is duplicate, say so. I Have not found it, only for PHP but for Perl. So If I can write full name of e.g. `Class::sub()` or `$Class::scalar`, I can write `Class->sub` or `$Class->scalar`(in case I have `use`d or `require`d the `Class`), what is the main difference in perl?

The problem is:
Class Animal.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package Animal;
our $VERSION = '0.01';
sub speak {
    my $class = shift;
    print "a $class goes ", $class->sound;
}
sub sound{
    die "You have to defined sound() in a subclass";
}
```

Then Class Horse.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package Horse;
use Animal;
our @ISA = qw[Animal];
our $VERSION = '0.01';
sub sound { 'neight' }
1
```

And if I, in main program do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
BEGIN{ unshift @INC, 'dirWithModules' }
 use Horse; use Animal;use Cow;
Animal::speak('Horse');
```

output---->`"a Horse goes neight"`
BUT IF I OD

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
BEGIN{ unshift @INC, 'dirWithModules' }
 use Horse; use Animal;use Cow;
Animal->speak('Horse')
```

output--->`"You have to defined sound() in a subclass at Animal.pm"`

So my question is, If I reference my method from class `Horse.pm` iherited sub `speak` from `Animal.pm` with `::`, double colon, the NO PROBLEM - it will print the sound. However if I try to reference the sub with `->` arrow, The `$class` is not inherited - that is, `$class` is `Animal.pm` itself, but not as parameter sent (`'Horse'`). So In what is `::` and `->` different?

Comment: It's a good idea read the official documentation: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html

Comment: @MiguelPrz The documentation can be quite intimidating for a beginner. Since I am experienced, I knew to open perlop (to find `->`), which lead me to perlobj. It's easy for someone who knows the answer to say "rtfm", but much harder for a beginner to find where/what the relevant documentations are (especially in that case since the answer is split in perlmod and perobj).

Comment: @dada and OP, a great place to begin, which is mentioned in the first line of `perlobj`, is the tutorial [`perlootut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foo->bar()` is a method call.

- It will use inheritance if necessary.
- It will pass the invocant (the left side of `->`) as the first argument. As such, `bar` should be written as follows:

  ```
  # Class method (Foo->bar)
  sub bar {
     my ($class, ...) = @_;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  # Object method (my $foo = Foo->new; $foo->bar)
  sub bar {
     my ($self, ...) = @_;
  }
  ```

`Foo::bar()` is a sub call.

- It won't use inheritance.