# what is the difference between double colon and arrow in Perl where the left hand side is a package name

Tags: perl

I think this is not QUITE a duplicate of this:
[Difference between double colon and arrow in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453648/difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow-in-perl)

My question is whether there is any difference between option 1 and 2 below:

```
use Time::Piece;
Time::Piece::strptime("Sun 3rd Nov, 1943", "%A %drd %b, %Y"); # option 1
Time::Piece->strptime("Sun 3rd Nov, 1943", "%A %drd %b, %Y"); # option 2
```

Comment: *"I think this is not QUITE a duplicate ...."* - it is a clear duplicate in my opinion. The difference is explained in the answer to the other question: the first is a function call and the second a method call, which also means that the first argument in the second case is the class name.

Comment: It is an exact duplicate. You used Time::Piece::strptime instead of Animal::speak or Foo::Bar, and you used Time::Piece->strptime instead of Animal->speak or Foo->bar.

Comment: You're right, my bad, should have seen that.  Oops.  Sorry.

Comment: But then the docs for `Time::Piece` seem to not match the source code.  They say that `strptime` should be called as a method and indeed many subs in that module (such as `mon_list`) are coded "defensively" so they work either way, it seems to me that `strptime`  is NOT written defensively and should fail when invoked as a method.  What am I missing?